# jQuery POST request always returns 404 not found with Laravel 4

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Every time I try to make a POST request with jQuery I keep receiving back the 404 error.

This is the `UserController.php`:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function signUp($username, $password, $email) {

        $user = new User();
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setPassword($password);
        $user->setEmail($email);

        return 'OK';
    }
}
```

And this is the `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/signup', function(){

    return View::make('signup');
});

Route::post('/signup/{username}/{password}/{email}', 'UserController@signUp');
```

I always receive this error:

```
POST http://192.168.0.102/webname/public/signup 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is that? If I try to navigate to `http://192.168.0.102/webname/public/signup` the page is loaded and the signup form is shown.

Comment: Why do you have `/webname/public` in your URL? That looks awful.

Comment: I know, but i just set Laravel up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're are using a "GET" type route.

Let me explain.

If you want to use a route like */route/{something}/{different}*
you have to manualy generate an URL matching that route.

```
URL::route('route', $something, $different)
```

Variable passed thought POST method are only available in the HTTP Headers.

So you can't call Route::post('/route/{variable}') by passing *variable* though POST method.
Only with Route::get().

To get your variable with POST use

```
Input::get('your_variable_name')
```

in your controller action.

Sorry for my bad english... A little bit tired, and I'm french too !

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have solved my problem :) Don't worry about your english, it's fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You are defining

```
Route::post('/signup/{username}/{password}/{email}', 'UserController@signUp');
```

But trying to access: /webname/public/signup.

That pattern does not exist for POST, but just for GET.

Answer (score 0):

I had some troubles that were related to this discussion and in my opinion did not merit their own post: jQuery *post* requests kept getting handled by my Laravel *get* controller.

My routes:

```
Route::controller('/test','TestController');
```

In my view :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: '/test/x/',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My Controller:

```
public function getX() {
    return 'Get';
}     
public function postX() {
    return 'Post';
}
```

On page load, I expected to see an alert reading "Post"... but instead I kept seeing "Get".  Laravel was routing the post request to the get controller.

Solving this had to do with the trailing slash.  Apparently, Laravel interpreted "/test/x/" as a GET route, but "/test/x" as a POST route.  So the lesson is that Laravel routing can be subtle.  Hope that helps clarify the discussion a bit.